# highcharts dynamic categories not working

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I am using the below method to populate the categories in highcharts dynamically but it is not working for me

```
var weeklyIndicators;
var cats = '';
$.when(
    $.getJSON('weeklyindicators', function(data) {
        weeklyIndicators = data;
    })
).then(function() {


    $.each(weeklyIndicators, function(i, item) {
        if (cats.indexOf(item.indicatorTimestamp) == -1){
            cats += "'" +  item.indicatorTimestamp + "'" + ',';
        }
    });
    cats = cats.substring(0, cats.length - 1);
    console.log(cats);
    // here is the output: '2016-01-30','2016-01-31','2016-02-01','2016-02-02','2016-02-03','2016-02-04','2016-02-05'
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [cats],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4]

        }]
    });
});
```

If I copy/paste the output from console.log, it is working fine, any help?

Below is a screenshot

[image]

Also, I need the series to be dynamic, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you post response data? I mean the response received by $.getJSON(your url) ?

Comment: the answer from @NishithKantChaturvedi is definitely the way to do this. 'categories' is an array - much better to build and specify it as an array rather than trying to build a string that mimics the structure of an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
var cats =[]
 $.each(weeklyIndicators, function(i, item) {
    if (cats.indexOf(item.indicatorTimestamp) == -1){
        cats.push(item.indicatorTimestamp);
    }
});
```

and use this **cats** array in your categories directly

```
categories = cats //not in []
```